# Need assistance getting a sum of a column based on the date range in another column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft Access and I have a table that has 3 columns, Employee_Name, In Actual Time, and Out Actual Time.

I want to get a sum of hours worked based on a date range; for example, get a sum of hours worked between 7/19/21 - 7/25/21, and group them by Employee_Name.  I was able to use DateDiff to get a raw amount of hours per day/row, but I can't figure out how to make a query make a sum of those raw hours based on the date range in the [In Actual Time] field.  I tried to find the answer on my own but it seems I'm spinning my wheels and I have no working prototypes as of yet.

I would greatly appreciate any insight anyone may be able to provide on an easy way to do this.

[image: A sample of the table.]

Comment: Which SQL engine do you use?

Comment: @juergend MS Access, sorry; edited my post to include that information.

Comment: did you try: `select Employee_Name, sum(datediff("n", in_time, out_time))
from your_table 
group by Employee_Name`

Comment: I did, that works as far as giving me a raw sum of hours over the 14 day period; but I can't figure out how to get two separate sums based on the date.  This is essentially a 14-day pay period with two individual pay weeks, and I can get the total hours worked, but I can't get two separate sums that are dependent on the date range.

Comment: You should add the expected output for your example data

Comment: Why are dates aligned left? Are fields date/time or text type?

Comment: You want to sum each week within a given date range? Options: 1) calculate first date of each week based on In Actual Time field and group on that or 2) extract week number from In Actual Time field and group on that. Will time period ever cross midnight? If data is multi-year, will need to consider year in filtering and grouping. And do you want week to cross years?

Comment: Add a _Group By_ for the year-week (2021W32), for example by using the function `FormatWeekIso8601` found at [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date) in module `DateText`.